# appendChild() issue on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

**Final Output**:I am trying to add Students and teachers on button clicks and display them separately.

My JS :

```
function SchoolAdmission(name, age, department) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = department;
}

SchoolAdmission.prototype.display = function() {
    var print = document.createElement("div");
    print.innerHTML = "Name: " + this.name + ", age:" + this.age + ", depart: " + this.department + "<br><br><br>";
    $("button").click(function() {
        if (this.id === "addStudent") {
            document.getElementById('studentList').appendChild(print);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('teacherList').appendChild(print);
        }
    });
};
addMember = function addMember() {
    var s1 = new SchoolAdmission();
    s1.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    s1.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    s1.department = document.getElementById('department').value;
    s1.display();
};
```

Here's my **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/LPu9x/

Basically am trying to do using prototype.

So my **issues** are:

1)On clicking the "Add student" or "Add Teacher",the data ends up in the wrong side. **(Resolved)**

2)Can this program be done in a more efficient way?(Using Prototype)

Comment: @VisioN its inside click event handler..so this.id should be buttons id

Comment: @Pilot-yup was gna say that.. :)

Comment: @Pilot Ah, indeed. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Why are you nesting click handler in display method?

Comment: @A.Wolff So as to check which button was clicked,and to append to the respective lists.
Should i have commented?

Comment: OMG so poor code..why is your event handler inside function?..Horrible to reconstruct

Comment: @Pilot Yes,i know.. am learning.
Which is why i asked,can this be done any better.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function SchoolAdmission(name, age, department) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = department;
}

SchoolAdmission.prototype.display = function(nameButton) {
    var print = document.createElement("div");
    print.innerHTML = "Name: " + this.name + ", age:" + this.age + ", depart: " + this.department + "<br><br><br>";
    if (nameButton === "addStudent") {
        document.getElementById('studentList').appendChild(print);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('teacherList').appendChild(print);
    }
};
addMember = function addMember(e) {
    var s1 = new SchoolAdmission();
    s1.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    s1.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    s1.department = document.getElementById('department').value;
    s1.display(e.target.id);
};

 <button id="addStudent" onclick="addMember(event)">Add Student</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPu9x/3/

Comment: Hey paulo,thanx... :)
Initially my logic was to do a similar thing just like u did(By passing the button id to its respective functions.)

But is this the best method? (Using the protoype functionality)

Comment: In your scenario there is no reason to use because the prototype is usually used to simulate OOP (polimosfirsmo, ...), but I believe I have no contraindications

Answer (score 0):

Do you object to jQuery? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/LPu9x/4/)

JS

```
$('#name').focus();

$('#addStudent').click(function(){
    var studentname = $('#name').val();
    var studentage = $('#name').val();
    var dept = $('#name').val();
    $('#studentList').append('<li>' + studentname + '-' + studentage + '-' + dept + '</li>');
    $('input').val('');
});
$('#addTeacher').click(function(){
    var studentname = $('#name').val();
    var studentage = $('#name').val();
    var dept = $('#name').val();
    $('#teacherList').append('<li>' + studentname + '-' + studentage + '-' + dept + '</li>');
    $('input').val('');
});
```

Comment: Yes jquery would have been easier...
But i wanted to study js prototype... so thnx anyway :)